# How to set userLocale setting in php when launching a report in Jasper Server?

Tags: php, jasperserver

I'm running some reports in Jasper Server (version 7.1.0 build 20180504_1307) and I'm using the official "JasperReports Server PHP Client" (version 2.0.0) with php 7.2.3 (on Windows Server 2012 R2).

I'm trying to launch a report with a different locale than the default one. I mean using the parameter userLocale=it_IT, but when I print the constant REPORT_LOCALE inside the report I obtain "en_EN".

```
$controls = array(
    'userLocale' => "it_IT",
    'otherParameter' => $otherParameter
);
$client = new Client(JASPER_URI, JASPER_USERNAME, JASPER_PASSWORD);
$client -> setRequestTimeout(10000);
try {
    $report = $client->reportService()->runReport('/reports/FATTURE', 'pdf', null, null, $controls);
} ...
```

Note that the "otherParameter" is correctly passed to jasper server.

The reason I need to change locale is to have different symbols in the numeric format for the thousand separator and decimal separator, as I have modified in the file "\apache-tomcat\webapps\jasperserver\WEB-INF\bundles\jasperserver_config_it.properties", but it seems that jasper server just ignore it.

So my question is: how to change the locale setting when calling a jasper server report (displaying the thousand separator and decimal separator changed) ?

Thanks all for the support.